# Is it possible to implement vertical tabs using richfaces?

Tags: jsf, tabs, richfaces

HI

I would like to create vertical tabs using the  rich faces tab controls. Is it possible to do it ?

Are there any other jsf implementations that offer the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richfaces doesn't support vertical tab in tabPanel.

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html) for doing this